# signal to signal pediction using RNN and Keras

Tags: keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to reproduce the nice work [here](https://github.com/LukeTonin/keras-seq-2-seq-signal-prediction/blob/master/keras-seq2seq-signal-prediction.ipynb) and adapte it so that it reads real data from a file.
I started by generating random signals (instead of the generating methods provided in the above link). Unfortoutanyl, I could not generate the proper signals that the model can accept.

here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.utils import plot_model
input_sequence_length = 15 # Length of the sequence used by the encoder
target_sequence_length = 15 # Length of the sequence predicted by the decoder
import random

def getModel():# Define an input sequence.

    learning_rate = 0.01
    num_input_features = 1
    lambda_regulariser = 0.000001 # Will not be used if regulariser is None
    regulariser = None # Possible regulariser: keras.regularizers.l2(lambda_regulariser)
    layers = [35, 35]
    num_output_features=1
    decay = 0 # Learning rate decay
    loss = "mse" # Other loss functions are possible, see Keras documentation.



    optimiser = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate, decay=decay) # Other possible optimiser "sgd" (Stochastic Gradient Descent)


    encoder_inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, num_input_features))

    # Create a list of RNN Cells, these are then concatenated into a single layer
    # with the RNN layer.
    encoder_cells = []
    for hidden_neurons in layers:
        encoder_cells.append(keras.layers.GRUCell(hidden_neurons, kernel_regularizer=regulariser,recurrent_regularizer=regulariser,bias_regularizer=regulariser))

    encoder = keras.layers.RNN(encoder_cells, return_state=True)
    encoder_outputs_and_states = encoder(encoder_inputs)

    # Discard encoder outputs and only keep the states.
    # The outputs are of no interest to us, the encoder's
    # job is to create a state describing the input sequence.
    encoder_states = encoder_outputs_and_states[1:]

    # The decoder input will be set to zero (see random_sine function of the utils module).
    # Do not worry about the input size being 1, I will explain that in the next cell.
    decoder_inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, 1))

    decoder_cells = []
    for hidden_neurons in layers:
        decoder_cells.append(keras.layers.GRUCell(hidden_neurons,
                                                  kernel_regularizer=regulariser,
                                                  recurrent_regularizer=regulariser,
                                                  bias_regularizer=regulariser))

    decoder = keras.layers.RNN(decoder_cells, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)

    # Set the initial state of the decoder to be the ouput state of the encoder.
    # This is the fundamental part of the encoder-decoder.
    decoder_outputs_and_states = decoder(decoder_inputs, initial_state=encoder_states)

    # Only select the output of the decoder (not the states)
    decoder_outputs = decoder_outputs_and_states[0]

    # Apply a dense layer with linear activation to set output to correct dimension
    # and scale (tanh is default activation for GRU in Keras, our output sine function can be larger then 1)
    decoder_dense = keras.layers.Dense(num_output_features,
                                       activation='linear',
                                       kernel_regularizer=regulariser,
                                       bias_regularizer=regulariser)

    decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

    # Create a model using the functional API provided by Keras.
    # The functional API is great, it gives an amazing amount of freedom in architecture of your NN.
    # A read worth your time: https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/ 
    model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], outputs=decoder_outputs)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimiser, loss=loss)
    print(model.summary())
    return model

def getXY():

    X, y = list(), list()
    for _ in range(100):
        x = [random.random() for _ in range(input_sequence_length)]
        y = [random.random() for _ in range(target_sequence_length)]
        X.append([x,[0 for _ in range(input_sequence_length)]])
        y.append(y)
    return np.array(X), np.array(y)

X,y = getXY()
print(X,y)
model = getModel()
model.fit(X,y)
```

The error message i got is:

> ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays
>   that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected.
>   Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1
>   arrays:

what is the correct shape of the input data for the model?

Answer (score 0):

If you read carefully the source of your [inspiration](https://github.com/LukeTonin/keras-seq-2-seq-signal-prediction/blob/master/keras-seq2seq-signal-prediction.ipynb), you will find that he talks about the "decoder_input" data.

He talks about the "teacher forcing" technique that consists of feeding the decoder with some delayed data. But also says that it didn't really work well in his case so he puts that initial state of the decoder to a bunch of 0 as this [line shows](https://github.com/LukeTonin/keras-seq-2-seq-signal-prediction/blob/dc16a728b8cb403ab10e9d98f7fc850f799847be/utils.py#L72):

```
decoder_input = np.zeros((decoder_output.shape[0], decoder_output.shape[1], 1))
```

in his design of the auto-encoder, they are two separate models that have different inputs, then he ties them with RNN stats from each other.

I can see that  you have tried doing the same thing but you have appended `np.array([x_encoder, x_decoder])` where you should have done `[np.array(x_encoder), np.array(x_decoder)]`. Each input to the network should be a numpy array that you put in a list of inputs, not one big numpy array.

I also found some typos in your code, you are appending `y` to itself, where you should instead create a `Y` variable

```
def getXY():

    X_encoder, X_decoder, Y = list(), list(), list()
    for _ in range(100):
        x_encoder = [random.random() for _ in range(input_sequence_length)]
        # the decoder input is a sequence of 0's same length as target seq
        x_decoder = [0]*len(target_sequence_length)
        y = [random.random() for _ in range(target_sequence_length)]
        X_encoder.append(x_encoder)
        # Not really optimal but will work
        X_decoder.append(x_decoder)
        Y.append(y)
    return [np.array(X_encoder), np.array(X_decoder], np.array(Y)
```

now when you do :

```
X, Y = getXY()
```

you receive X which is a list of 2 numpy arrays (as your model requests) and Y which is a single numpy array.

I hope this helps

**EDIT**

Indeed, in the code that generates the dataset, you can see that they build 3 dimensions np arrays for the input. RNN needs 3 dimensional inputs :-)

The following code should address the shape issue:

```
def getXY():

    X_encoder, X_decoder, Y = list(), list(), list()
    for _ in range(100):
        x_encoder = [random.random() for _ in range(input_sequence_length)]
        # the decoder input is a sequence of 0's same length as target seq
        x_decoder = [0]*len(target_sequence_length)
        y = [random.random() for _ in range(target_sequence_length)]
        X_encoder.append(x_encoder)
        # Not really optimal but will work
        X_decoder.append(x_decoder)
        Y.append(y)

        # Make them as numpy arrays
        X_encoder = np.array(X_encoder)
        X_decoder = np.array(X_decoder)
        Y = np.array(Y)

        # Make them 3 dimensional arrays (with third dimension being of size 1) like the 1d vector: [1,2] can become 2 de vector [[1,2]]
        X_encoder = np.expand_dims(X_encoder, axis=2)
        X_decoder = np.expand_dims(X_decoder, axis=2)
        Y = np.expand_dims(Y, axis=2)

    return [X_encoder, X_decoder], Y
```

Comment: thanks! that is a bit strange now. X_encoder is not defined, you just append x_encoder to it.

Comment: No. ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (100, 15)